# EditText with dots

Tags: android, android-edittext

```
final EditText Edt= new EditText(this);
Edt.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(100,30));
Edt.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
Edt.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 0);
Edt.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 15);
Edt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
Edt.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
```

I want to allow .(dot) in EditText in java code, how to do it ?

Comment: Why do you want this? Do you want to provide a text-field where a user can input an IP address or something like that? If so, it might be simpler to just provide four smaller text-input fields and just let the user input up to three numerals in each.

Comment: i need to allow the amount(rs)

Answer (score 0):

May be below code is usefull for you:

Edt.setSingleLine();

this will show one line text upto EditText width and it removes extra text and put .(dot) insteed of that.

Comment: but i want to allow numbers and dot only,, not text

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is still interested in this:

```
     Edt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

Now the EditText only allows Numbers and dots.